# Pi-subgroup in group

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb{P}$ is a set primes numbers, $\pi \subseteq P$ and $\pi
^{\prime }=P-\pi $

Let $O_{\pi }\left( G\right) =\left\langle N~;~N\trianglelefteq G\text{ and }%
N\text{ is }\pi \text{-subgroup}\right\rangle $

Is it true that $O_{\pi }\left( G\right) =1\Longrightarrow G$ is $\pi
^{\prime }-$group?

if it is true, could not it have other $H$ $\pi $-subgroup (not normal) in $G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. Let $\pi=\{2\}$ and $G$ be non-abelian of order 6. Then $O_\pi(G) = 1$, but $|G|$ is divisible by 2.

Comment: Perhaps you can find a counterexample. Using the same $G$.

Comment: And $O_{\pi ^{\prime }}\left( G\right) =1\Longrightarrow G$ is $%
\pi -$group?Is it worth the same argument for that case?